# Split data from API

Tags: angular

I fetch data from an API. There are three fields: title, timestamp (unix) and a description.

I need in the frontend (Angular) date and time from the timestamp. How can I split the timestamp from the API into the two fields?

```
this.HeroService.getPublicHero()
.subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero,
err => this.error = err);
```

I assign the data to the model here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Timestamp column on your DB table. 
then just declare;

```
timestamp: any;

this.HeroService.getPublicHero()
.subscribe(hero => {
    this.timestamp = hero.yourtimestampcoulmnname,
});
```